# If cel.Val = "A0_" & A Then

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook where I want to find the cell that contains "A0_" & A where A is the value from another worksheet. The end goal is to copy the column with "A0_" & A to another sheet titled. Here is my code so far.

```
Sub Copy_A()

Dim A As String
Dim iRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim dataws As Worksheet
Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, NewRng As Range

Set dataws = Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet")

Set iRng = dataws.Range(dataws.Cells(1, 1), dataws.Cells(1, dataws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

A = Worksheets("Information Sheet").Range("E12").Value

For Each cel In iRng
If cel.Value = "A0_" & A Then
    Set Rng1 = cel.EntireColumn.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    Debug.Print Rng1.FormulaR1C1
    Set Rng2 = dataws.Cells(Rng1.Row - 1, Rng1.Column + 1)
    Debug.Print Rng2.FormulaR1C1
    Set Rng3 = Cells(cel.Row + 1, cel.Column)
    Debug.Print Rng3.FormulaR1C1
End If
Next cel

With dataws
Set NewRng = .Range(Rng3.Address & ":" & Rng1.Address)
Debug.Print NewRng.Address
NewRng.Select
End With


End Sub
```

For some reason the code does not recognize "A0_" & A when it reaches that cell. The code goes through each column but does not execute setting the ranges. Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated! Here is a picture of my workbook to give you a better idea of what is happening 
[image]

Comment: Step through your code and make sure that `A` equals what you think it should.

Comment: ^^ and even ensure it has no leading / trailing spaces.

Comment: A does equal what I want it to equal.

Comment: Place a line saying `Debug.Print cel.Column & "|" & cel.Value & "|A0_" & A & "|"` just after `For Each cel In iRng` and see what is written to the immediate window - ensure that one of the lines written is showing the same values in both the `cel.Value` part and the `A0_" & A` part.

Comment: BTW - Not related to your problem (as far as I can see) but you should declare `Rng1`, `Rng2` and `Rng3` to be `Range` instead of `Variant`, and you should use `dataws.Columns.Count` instead of just `Columns.Count`.

Comment: Added the line and Formula, FormulaArray, FormulaLocal, FormulaR1C1 remain the same. Also I have Rng1, Rng2, Rng3 declared as Range not Variant and in my workbook A is equal to a value for example say 1

Comment: What was written to the Immediate Window?  Was the line `2|A0_1|A0_1` written?  (And you have `Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, NewRng As Range` which is equivalent to `Dim Rng1 As Variant, Rng2 As Variant, Rng3 As Variant, NewRng As Range` - `Variant` is the default data type if you don't specify anything.)

Comment: Ok so stepping through the code the first time 1|Depth|A0_2| appears and then stepping when it goes back to the Debug.Print cel.Column & "|" & cel.Value & "|A0_" & A & "|" and I step through a second time 2|A0_ 1|A0_2| appears.

Comment: Keep stepping through, if `A` is `2` you should hopefully get to a line saying `9|A0_2|A0_2|`.  Once that is printed, I would expect your code to go to the `Set Rng1 = cel.EntireColumn.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)` line.